# Если форма заполнена верно, отправить ее

Tags: форма, submit, javascript

День добрый, никак не могу победить форму...
Задача такова, по кнопке "отправить", проверить заполненность формы (сделано), и в случае если форма заполнена верно - отправить ее... что только не пытался изобретать)

```
<form id='reg' name='reg'>
  <input 1....>
  <input 2....>
  <input type=submit>// в таком варианте как не извращался форма в любом случае отправляется
  <input type=button>// в таком варианте как не извращался форма в любом случае НЕ отправляется    
</form>
```

код js доходил до обсурда

```
 onclick='this.form.submit();'
```

и в подобном духе найденом на просторах интернета

если не сложно напишите как отправить форму из JS или как отменить отправку с помощью JS

Comment: jQuery использовать можно?

Comment: <input type=button>

Не вызывает события submit и семантически неправильно обрабатывать этот тип кнопки для подписи формы. Ответьте на вопрос про jQuery, все на самом деле просто

Comment: Да можно, сейчас подключена версия 1.2 чегото там) могу подключить новей

по поводу неправильности сего действа, можно ли тогда в скрипте отменить submit для типа кнопки <input type=submit> ? т.е. если в результате проверки нашлась ошибка в данных)

Comment: http://htmlbook.ru/html/input/required , а для старых браузеров полифил.

Comment: @pvkovalev, вроде небыло у меня таких вопросов) я сразу ответил что можно и что версия 1.2. чего то там уже подключена, и лиш уточнил что ежели нужна более новая то проблем это не составит) а за ответ спасибо) буду тестить)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если не использовать ajax отправку данных, то код будет таким:

```
$('#reg').on('submit', function () {
    var validation = true;
    if (validation) {
        // валидация успешна, данные пойдут на сервер
        return true;
    }
    else {
        // валидация не пройдена, надо вывести ошибки и не отправлять форму
        return false;
    }
});
```

И не обрабатывайте input типа button, т.к. отправку можно осуществить нажатием Enter в текстовом input-е

Comment: Благодарен за ответ) все случилось как надо)